# pandas - calculating new column from calculating from different rows

Tags: pandas, row, calculated-columns

Given a pandas dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'date': ['20200315', '20200314', '20200313'], 'units': [700, 500, 400]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
   date       units
0  20200315   700
1  20200314   500
2  20200313   400
```

How can I create a new column - 'change' - where the value is equal to the units of today minus the units from yesterday?  Is there a way to do it easily other than iterating through each row and storing the values of each unit before doing the math?  I want to end up with:

```
   date       units   change
0  20200315   700     200
1  20200314   500     100
2  20200313   400     0
```

Comment: For future reference, indenting tables you paste by 4-spaces, or selecting all of it and clicking the `{}` button in the editor, renders it in code blocks like above making it easier to read

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by date, use rolling,then apply the difference between the values and finally fill nan with 0 :

```
df['change'] = df.sort_values(by='date')['units'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1] - x.iloc[0]).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the dates are already ordered, and if so, you can use the [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff) method :

```
 df['change'] = df.units.diff(-1).fillna(0)

     date      units    change
0   20200315    700     200.0
1   20200314    500     100.0
2   20200313    400     0.0
```